# How can you in Java list all files recursively in a folder that do not match an array of extensions?

Tags: java, file

I have a simple program that I am making that looks through a directory recursively and removes all files that do not match the files extensions chosen by the user. (essentially I am remaking a script that I wrote in PHP to help teach myself java)

The method works fine except that it returns an array of files that match the array of extensions. This would remove the wrong files. How can I return the files that do not match?

I am using org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils with a string array to get the files:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class Recurse {
// The method that takes a directory path (file object called folder) and a string of extensions
    public static List<File> getFiles(final File folder, String[] extensions) throws IOException{

    List<File> fileList = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(folder, extensions, true);

    return fileList;
    }
}
```

I have found examples that use just one file type e.g ".txt" but cannot find one for an array. I would prefer to stick with org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils but I am willing to change my method.

Comment: Wait, why do you want to exclude files by extension? Could you use `FileUtils` to find all files then test the extensions yourself?

Comment: That is basically what I'm looking for but I'm not sure how to go about it using Java. If you have a code example that would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with rcook's answer, but if you REALLY want to stick with `FileUtils`, here's an alternative: get all the files, then remove the ones that match the extensions.

```
List<File> all = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(folder, null, true);
List<File> unwanted = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(folder, extensions, true);
all.removeAll(unwanted);
return all;
```

Note this is a bit wasteful, involving two recursions through the filesystem.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. But I do agree that it would be wasteful to loop through twice. Do you have an example of a more "correct" way of accomplishing this?

Comment: It would vary. The php script was originally written to remove all non image files from a couple hundred directories with thousands of files on a linux based hosting server. Then it just evolved from there. Now I'm just using it as a starter for java.

Comment: That doesn't sound performance critical, so the extra recursion may not be an issue.

Comment: No performance isn't the biggest deal in this case, but I am always looking for the faster, more efficient way to code a program. I also appreciate the pure java answer based off of jcooks response. I wish I could also give him credit as well. Thank you both for fast, correct responses to my problem. This is the first question I've ever asked on here and it was a very positive experience

Answer (score 1):

Use File.listFiles(), and use a java.io.FileFilter.  You write the filter to examine the filename and determine whether that file 'passes through' the filter.  Instantiate your filter with the array of extensions you don't want or whatever.  You aren't using FileUtils, but you don't need anything outside of standard Java libraries.

--

Edit after request for example

```
public class NotTheseExtensions implements java.io.FileFilter
{
  private ArrayList<String> extensions;

  public NotTheseExtensions(ArrayList<String> extensions)
  {
    this.extensions = extensions;
  }

  public boolean accept(String filename)
  {
    boolean result = true;
    boolean inList = false;  // set this in your own logic

    // logic to get the extension from the filename and look to see if it is
    // in your list -- hopefully I don't have to write that for you as well.
    if (inList) { result = false; }

    return result;
  }
}
```

Now, look at the (various) signatures for listFiles in java.io.File.  One of them takes such a file filter.  Only things that pass your file filter, i.e., return true in the accept() method above, will be returned by listFiles() when given this filter.

Comment: Do you have a small example of how I would accomplish this?

Comment: This is the best pure Java way of doing it, but the code in the question does a recursive search through subdirectories, which is a lot more code in pure Java than using FileUtils.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the files in the directory and then just remove the files that you get for extensions that you dont want.

I use this to get files with particular extension:

```
File dir = new File(fileDir);
FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter("*.txt");
File[] files = dir.listFiles(fileFilter);
```

Comment: This is very close to what I am looking for except my problem is that I would not know all of the possible extensions that are in the folder.

Comment: you dont need to know the extensions. You can get a list of all the files irrespective of the extensions. And then remove the files from that list, for which you dont want the extensions. You can get it by:
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
File[] files = new File("/path/to/the/directory").listFiles();

for (File file : files) {
    if (file.isFile()) {
        results.add(file.getName());
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Here's the pure java alternative to using `FileUtils`, avoiding the efficiency problem of my other answer and supporting recursion. This involves so much code I think I would favour the `FileUtils` solution.

```
public void myMethod() {
    List<File> files = recursiveList(folder, new String[] { "jpg", "png" });
    // ... do something ...
}

private List<File> recursiveList(File folder, String[] rejectedExtensions) {
    List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
    for (File subfolder : folder.listFiles(new DirectoryFilter())) {
        files.addAll(recursiveList(subfolder, rejectedExtensions));
    }
    files.addAll(Arrays.asList(folder.listFiles(new ExtensionFilter(rejectedExtensions))));
    return files;
}

private class DirectoryFilter implements FileFilter {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        return file.isDirectory();
    }
}

private class ExtensionFilter implements FileFilter {

    private final String[] rejectedExtensions;

    public ExtensionFilter(String[] rejectedExtensions) {
        this.rejectedExtensions = rejectedExtensions;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            return false;
        }
        String name = file.getName();
        for (String rejectedExtension : rejectedExtensions) {
            if (name.endsWith(rejectedExtension)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```